Hille-Yosida Generation Theorem
I am currently reading the book by Engel and Nagel on Semi Groups, specifically the proof of the Hille-Yosida Generation Theorem (Theorem 3.5 in Chapter 2, Section 3) and I am stuck on the following: We have shown that, for fixed $x\in D(A)$, the orbit maps $\xi_n : t\mapsto T_n(t) x$ converge uniformly to $\xi : t\mapsto T(t)x$ on every compact intervall $[0,t_0].$ I haven't been able to show that the differentiated orbit maps $\dot{\xi}_n : t\mapsto T_n(t) A_n x$ also converge uniformly on $[0,t_0]$ to $\eta : t\mapsto T(t)Ax$. Using the triangle inequality, we get
$\lvert T_n(t) A_n x - T(t) Ax\rvert \leq \lvert T_n(t) (A_n x - Ax)\rvert + \lvert (T_n(t) - T(t))Ax\rvert\leq \lvert A_n(x) - Ax\rvert + \lvert (T_n(t) - T(t))Ax\rvert$
since $\{T_n(t)\}_{t\geq 0}$ is a strongly continuous semigroup of contractions. By the pointwise convergence $A_n x \to Ax,$ the first term on the right hand side converges to $0$ uniformly in $t$. The second term converges pointwise to $0$ since we know that $T_n(t)x \to T(t)x$ for all $x\in X$ and $t\geq 0$ by step (i). For uniform convergence, we can't use the estimate $(3.9)$, namely
$\lvert T_n(t) x - T_m(t) x\rvert \leq t\lvert A_n x - A_m x\rvert,$
which for $m\to \infty$ turns to
$\lvert T_n(t) x - T(t)x\rvert \leq t\lvert A_n x - Ax\rvert,$
since $Ax$ doesn't have to be in $D(A)$.
Any help is appreciated.

I assume that $A_n= nA R_{n}$ is the Yosida approximation of $A$ and $T_n(t) = e^{tA_n}$ is the uniformly continuous semi-group generated by the bounded operator $A_n$.  For  $x \in D(A)$ you have that
$$\|T_n(t) x - T_m(t) x\| \le t \|A_nx - A x\| $$
so that for $x \in D(A^2)$ (that is, $x \in D(A)$ and $Ax \in D(A)$)
$$\|T_n(t) Ax-T_m(t) Ax \| \le t \|A_n Ax - A^2 x \|. $$
To bypass the extra regularity condition of $x$ being in $D(A^2)$ you can use the fact that

Fact: $D(A^2)$ is dense in $D(A)$ for the graph norm $|u|= \|u\| + \|Au\|$.

Then, given $x \in D(A)$ and $ε>0$ let $u \in D(A^2)$ be such that $\|x-u\|<ε$ and $\|Ax-Au\|<ε$. One has
\begin{align*}
\|T_n(t) Ax-T(t) Ax \| & \le \|T_n(t) Ax-T_n(t) Au\| + \|T_n(t) Au- T(t) Au \|
+ \|T(t) Au - T(t) Ax\|
\\
& \le \|Ax-Au\| +\|T_n(t) Au-T(t) Au\| + \|Au-Ax\| 
\\ 
& \le 2 ε + t \|A_n Au -A^2u\|
\end{align*}
so that
$t \mapsto T_n(t) Ax$ converges to $t \mapsto T(t) Ax$ uniformly on bounded intervals $[0,t_0]$.

The proof of the fact is very simple: Given $x \in D(A)$ and $ε>0$  you have that
$$ n R_n (x)  x \to x,  \quad   n AR_n \to  Ax$$
and so by taking $u = n R_n x $ for sufficiently large $n$  you have that $\|u-x\|<ε, \|Au-Ax\|<ε$. It remains to verify that $u \in D(A^2)$ i.e. $Au \in D(A)$. But, since $n^2 R_nx - nAR_λx = nx$ you get that $Au = n^2R_nx-nx \in D(A)$.

Thank you for your answer! In a previous section, it was even proved that $D(A^\infty),$ which is the intersection of $D(A^k), k\in \mathbb{N}$, is dense in $D(A)$ for the graph norm. However, I feel like there should be an easier solution since the authors didn't add any explanation to the statement. If this isn't the case, then I will accept your answer.
